# iOS / sqlite - How to print a prepared sqlite3_stmt to NSLog

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, prepared-statement, nslog

I'm having some unexpected results with the data i'm inserting or replacing into my sqlite database.  To trouble shoot the problem I'm trying to get a full print out of the prepared sqlite3_stmt (statement) in the below code.

What I would like to do is something like this, but I know it doesn't work:

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"%@", statement);
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Thanks!!

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (true) {

    ListingsObject *temp = (ListingsObject *) DatabaseObject;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &conyDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *insertReplaceStmt = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO listings (id, association_id, name, email, phone, toll_free_phone, fax, website, street, city, state, zipcode, county, bio, featured, hours, lat, lng, updated, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(conyDB, insertReplaceStmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [temp._id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [temp.associationId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [temp.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [temp.email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [temp.phone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [temp.tollFreePhone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [temp.fax UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [temp.website UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [temp.street UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [temp.city UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11, [temp.state UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 12, [temp.zipcode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [temp.county UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 14, [temp.bio UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 15, [temp.featured UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 16, [temp.hours UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 17, [temp.lat UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 18, [temp.lng UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 19, [temp.updated UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 20, [temp.status UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Insert or Replace to Listing Table successful Listing = %@", temp.name);

        }else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add to Listing table Listing = %@", temp.name);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
 sqlite3_close(conyDB);
```

UPDATE:
I haven't found an answer to this question. But I needed to move on so I ended up just constructing a string with NSLog(); as below for each one of my tables I had to check:

```
NSLog(@"     INSERT OR REPLACE INTO listings (id, association_id, name, email, phone, toll_free_phone, fax, website, street, city, state, zipcode, county, bio, featured, hours, lat, lng, updated, status) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", temp._id, temp.associationId, temp.name, temp.email, temp.phone, temp.tollFreePhone, temp.fax
                  , temp.website, temp.street, temp.city, temp.state, temp.zipcode, temp.county, temp.bio, temp.featured, temp.hours, temp.lat, temp.lng, temp.updated, temp.status);
```

Comment: What problem you are getting ? What is the error ? Can you plz post that ?

Comment: I'm not get any error.  It is just that the behavior of my database isn't working as expected.  I would like to do trouble shooting in a sqlite manager program where I can quickly try different variation of this and other statements.  If I could print out what is going on it would be very quick for me to copy any paste it over.  Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can print the compiled statement but you can print the sql query.. if you are new to sqlite in iOS I would strongly recommend you FMDB .. its a very good wrapper for sqlite.. you can find it on github https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not find any standard method to this, so I made my own:

```
-(NSMutableString*) sqlite3StmtToString:(sqlite3_stmt*) statement
{
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString new];
    [s appendString:@"{\"statement\":["];
    for (int c = 0; c < sqlite3_column_count(statement); c++){
        [s appendFormat:@"{\"column\":\"%@\",\"value\":\"%@\"}",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_name(statement, c)],[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, c)]];
        if (c < sqlite3_column_count(statement) - 1)
            [s appendString:@","];
    }
    [s appendString:@"]}"];
    return s;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self sqlite3StmtToString:statement]);
```

Observation: I did it in same class because I call this with `self` but you can do in any class

Comment: I found this always breaks on a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `sqlite3_mutex_enter(db->mutex);` in `sqlite3.c`.

Comment: @ing0 sorry but I could not understand what you meant by that.

Comment: I ran your method against my compiled statment (sqlite3_stmt*) and there was an runtime error.

Comment: @ing0 understood, can you send-me the conditions when it occurs?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the statements that contain columns without assigned value (practically all select statements), sqlite3_column_text then returns nil and subsequent attempt to create UTF8 string causes crash. Check if the value is nil and it won't crash, but it will not help you probably as you need to some other function to get bound data (sqlite3_column_value ?)

Comment: in my case just returns an empty statement

Comment: @flatronka what you get with 'sqlite3_column_count(statement)' ?

Comment: this is the weird thing that I get 0 but I have 10 columns

Comment: @flatronka :/ the method sqlite3_column_count is standart of sqlite, how is your sql query?